# Yii2: Registering javascript when loading (nested) Gridview through renderAjax

Tags: yii2, pjax

I am using Yii2 and struggling to load a GridView (kartik\grid\GridView)  from within a an ExpandRowColumn (kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn) in a master Gridview using the detailUrl option.

Everything works fine when using the detail option, which loads all subgrids on page-load which destroys page load times. Using the detailUrl option, the subgrid loads properly, however pagination and sorting on the subgrids malfunction, as seemingly the javascript which is registered on with a Gridview on a normal page-load, does not seem initialised.

My code:

**ExpandableRowColumn**

```
$this->columns[] = [

                'class' => 'kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
                'expandOneOnly' => true,
                'width' => '50px',
                'visible' => true,
                'order' => DynaGrid::ORDER_FIX_LEFT,
                'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
                },
                'detailUrl' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/' . Yii::$app->controller->id . '/sector-details', 'filter' => $this->getSubgridFilter()]),

                /*
                  //Proper functioning code using detail option
                  'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                  $searchModel = new \app\models\search\Subject;
                  $searchModel->bySector = $key;
                  $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($this->getSubGridFilter());
                  return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('/linkage/_subgrid', [
                  'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                  'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                  'gridId' => $key,
                  ]);
                  },
                 * 
                 */
            ];
```

**Controller Action**

```
public function actionSectorDetails(array $filter = [])
{
    if (isset($_POST['expandRowKey'])) {
        $sectorId = $_POST['expandRowKey'];
        $searchModel = $this->_initSearch();
        $searchModel->bySector = $sectorId;
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search($filter);
        return $this->renderAjax('/linkage/_subgrid', [
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'gridId' => $sectorId,
        ]);
    } else {
        return '<div class="alert alert-danger">No data found</div>';
    }
}
```

**Gridview**

```
//ID examples: actor-subgrid-x
$gridId = Yii::$app->controller->id . '-subgrid-' . $gridId;
$glyph = app\helpers\IconHelper::getIcon($caller);



$gridConfig = [
    'simple' => true,
    'id' => $gridId . '-inner',
    'title' => $title,
    'model' => $searchModel,
    'provider' => $dataProvider,
    'pagerOptions' => ['linkOptions' => ['class' => 'item-link']]
];
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col⁻xs-12">
        <?php
        Pjax::begin(['id' => $gridId, 'enablePushState' => false]);
        DynaGrid::widget([
                    'columns' => $this->columns,
                    'storage' => DynaGrid::TYPE_COOKIE,
                    'theme' => $this->theme,
                    'userSpecific' => false,
                    'showPersonalize' => false,
                    'showFilter' => false,
                    'showSort' => false,
                    'allowThemeSetting' => false,
                    'gridOptions' => $this->gridOptions,
                    'options' => ['id' => $gridId], // a unique identifier is important
        ]);
        Pjax::end()
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is,whenever I click a pagination or a sorting link, it redirects to the link called by the detailUrl, i.e. sector-details, rather than the main controller action.

The javascript handling the PJAX to catch subgrid pagination and sorting does not seem loaded...

How can I fully load a Gridview using renderAjax?
Please Help!!

How can I get this sorted out